# Can't find documentation or declaration for Form::number() helper method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to find some more information on the Laravel `Form::number()` helper method that I'm using to generate a number input field in my form. I found an answer here a few days ago suggesting that I use this method, but I can't seem to locate this question again.

Basically, I'm looking specify the attributes array for the field, and I'm not sure what order the parameters for the method are in. I'd really like to find some documentation or a declaration of this Form Helper.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK, and the online docs nor API mention it, there's not such function in the `Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder` class: http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Html.FormBuilder.html

The closest thing to what you want might be a simple input element, with the number `type` attribute:

```
input( string $type, string $name, string $value = null, array $options = array() )
```

Example:

```
Form::input('number', 'inputname');
```

which creates:

```
<input type="number" name="inputname" value="">
```

If you look at the function definition for `Form::text()`, for example, you see that it's just a wrapper for the `Form::input()` method:

```
public function text($name, $value = null, $options = array())
{
   return $this->input('text', $name, $value, $options);
}
```

so you could extend the FormBuilder class, if you like, adding a similar function:

```
public function number($name, $value = null, $options = array())
{
   return $this->input('number', $name, $value, $options);
}
```

but if I may say it, it's pretty useless...

Comment: Yeah, I get that. There isn't any mention of it anywhere, but it exists. If you use `Form::number("numberField")`, it generates an input of type number! I might just have to use this way of doing it.

Comment: Well, if it exists, it's likely an analogue of Form::text(), so try using the same arguments. See my updated answer

Comment: In their official documentation (http://laravel.com/docs/html#number) they mention a Form::number input, but I get an error when trying to use that... Solution from Damien works for me though

Comment: @DamienPirsy do you know how to use `Form::input('number', 'inputname');` for decimal value